# Maven could not find Android 4.2 dependency

Tags: android, maven

I am building my android app with Maven (ok... trying to build), after several errors I got to this one :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project AndroidPro: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.kowalsk.android.recipe:AndroidPro:apk:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.google.android:android:jar:4.0.3 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

I used maven-android-sdk-deployer and downloaded all needed libraries, but it haven't solved the problem.

Comment: is the first time that you use maven? if It's you might have to configure it(proxy)

Comment: yep, first time. It appears that it only works on 2.3.3 API. Can u specify where I can configure it?

Comment: Hi, check this web site is quite easy, http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html

Comment: ok, I have it, but why I need to configure proxy ? It appears to connect to Maven Global for all dependencies beside this google APIs (exepct 2.3.3)

Comment: Sorry, I miss understood your question, try with this POM https://gist.github.com/yoshiki/1283185

Comment: Still the same, maybe there is somewhere set, to use only 2.3.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using maven-android-sdk-deployer : the stub for android libraries will be installed in your local maven repo with the groupId `android` (i.e. not `com.google.android`)

The groupId `com.google.android` is the official groupId used by google to publish some versions of android API. I don't know why only few versions are available (probably because maven wasn't the build tool choose by google for the android platform). We can hope that in a near future (mainly because google choose gradle as new build tool): all versions will be available with the groupId com.google.android in central repo.

In my local repo, the stubs installed with maven-android-sdk-deployer have also a special version number with `_rX` appended. So to use the 4.0.3 I have the following dependency :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3_r3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

See the link [Maven Android Jar](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22com.google.android%22%20AND%20a%3a%22android%22), maven repository does not have the version you mentioned in your pom `4.0.3`
use any version mentioned in the link.

Comment: I've checked this website and other versions and it works only on 2.3.3, weird